# Is $f: \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$ strictly increasing if locally strictly increasing everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, rational-numbers

(At the outset of this question, I will note that my background in analysis is introductory, derived from the first 11 chapters of Spivak's *Calculus*.)

I recently proved the following theorem:

> If the function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ has the property that for any $x \in \mathbb R$ there is a $\delta_x \gt 0$ such that on the interval $(x-\delta_x,x+\delta_x)$ $f$ is strictly increasing, then $f$ is a strictly increasing function $(\dagger)$.

Because Spivak has not introduced topological notions of "covers" or "compactness" (which seems to be the conventional way of proving this statement), I relied on the **Least Upper Bound Property** (LUBP), as Spivak covers this in Chapter 8.

This was a proof by contradiction, supposing there was some $x \lt y$ such that $f(x) \geq f(y)$. Ultimately, I used the following set to produce the contradiction:

$$S=\left\{z \in \mathbb R \ | \ z \gt x \text{ and } \forall w \in (x,z]\Big (f(x) \lt f(w) \Big)\right\}$$

---

After finishing this proof, I wondered whether or not the Least Upper Bound Property was the only reason I could carry out this proof.

I considered modifying $(\dagger)$ to $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ and $f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$. With some slight changes (e.g. requiring $\delta_x \gt 1$), it seems like the claim still remained valid despite not being able to invoke the LUBP (I suspect this is related to intervals in $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Z$ having some sense of finiteness...i.e. I can count the number of elements between $x$ and $y$ in the interval $[x,y]$).

I then came to modifying $(\dagger)$ to $f: \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$. To prove $(\dagger)$ in the original setting of $\mathbb R$, the LUBP seems to have let me sneak "right on top of" the set $S$, from a starting point of $y$. However, in the setting of $\mathbb Q$, where $S$ would be redefined as:

$$S_{\mathbb Q}=\left\{z \in \mathbb Q \ | \ z \gt x \text{ and } \forall w \in (x,z]\Big (f(x) \lt f(w) \Big)\right\}$$

(where $(x,z]$ should be understood to only contain elements of $\mathbb Q$) it does not seem to me that I will be able to get right on top of $S_{\mathbb Q}$.

**Should I conclude that the claim is false for $\mathbb Q$**? If so, might I have a counter example? Further, if false, then, given that the claim appears to be true in $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Z$, should I conclude that if my setting involves intervals $[x,y]$ that contain an infinite number of elements but **lacks** some flavor of the LUBP, the claim will always be false?

Comment: Maybe you can find an example of a function which is strictly increasing on $\{x\in\mathbb Q:x\lt\sqrt2\}$ and strictly increasing on $\{x\in\mathbb Q:x\gt\sqrt2\}$ but not strictly increasing on $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: Trust Mr "bof" --if  $f(x)=x$ on $\mathbb Q \cap (-\infty, \sqrt 2)$ with  $f(x)=x-1$ on $\mathbb Q \cap (\sqrt 2, \infty)$ you have your counterexample.   For the real line you can use the LUB property, Heine-Borel theorem, Bolzano-Weirstrass theorem, nested interval property, or Cousin's lemma.  In fact it is instructive in cases like this to try all of them and decide which is most attractive.

Comment: By the way, the claim is also false for naturals and integers: "locally increasing" is a void condition in their case, since you can take the interval to be a singleton. In all these cases (rationals, naturals, integers), you can find a locally increasing *bijection* which is not increasing.

Comment: @tomasz even though I stipulate that $\delta_x \gt 1$?

Comment: @S.Cramer: fair enough, if you do that, but that is not what is normally considered a "local" property.

Comment: Is the function supposed to be continuous?

Comment: @markvs No, in the context of this question, the function is not necessarily continuous. If it *is* continuous, though, does the result change for $\mathbb Q$? Further, if it is continuous, do I need to rely on the LUBP to prove for $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @markvs actually, I think I figured out the proof for $\mathbb R$ using continuity as the guiding principle. "Consider the continuous interval $[x,y]$. If $m \in (x,y]$ is the minimum, we will have contradictions because, by assumption, there will be an even smaller number in the neighborhood $(m-\delta_m,m)$. So $x$ is the minimum of $[x,y]$. $y$ was arbitrary so QED". Assuming that's the approach you were thinking, I guess I would comment that the claim: "The continuous interval $[x,y]$ has a minimum" is, indirectly, an invocation of the least upper bound property.

Comment: B. S. Thompson's example is a continuous function from $\Bbb Q \to \Bbb Q$. And concerning your restriction on $\delta_x$, for any $\epsilon > 0$, if for all $x \in \Bbb Q$ we have $\delta_x > \epsilon$, then "locally increasing" implies "increasing". If $y > x$ are two rationals, then there is an integer $n$ with $\frac{y-x}n < \epsilon$. Thus every consecutive pair of rationals in the sequence $\left\{x_k = x +k\frac{y-x}n\right\}_{k=0}^n$ are within $\epsilon$ of each other, and therefore the locally increasing condition gives $$f(x) \le f(x_1) \le \ldots \le f(x_{n-1}) \le f(y)$$